Read PBF Tiles with Android Google Map sdk
I want to display PBF Tiles with Android Google Map SDK.
I have this sample code with an UrlTileProvider who does not work
val tileProvider = object : UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
                override fun getTileUrl(p0: Int, p1: Int, p2: Int): URL? {
                    val url = URL("https://openmaptiles.geo.data.gouv.fr/data/cadastre/$p2/$p0/$p1.pbf")
                    return url
                }
            }
googleMap?.addTileOverlay(TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider))

What am I doing wrong ?
